# Saída não esperada na minha variavel!

Tags: c

```
# include <stdio.h>

float calcula_media_ponderada(int N_1, int N_2, int Peso_1, int Peso_2)
{
    float Media;
    Media = ((N_1 * Peso_1) + (N_2 * Peso_2)) / (Peso_1 + Peso_2);
    return Media; 
}

int main(void)
{
int Nota_1, Nota_2, Matricula, Peso_1, Peso_2;
float Media;
printf("Qual a matricula do aluno ? ");
scanf("%d", &Matricula);
printf("Qual a primeira nota do aluno ? ");
scanf("%d", &Nota_1);
printf("Qual o peso da primeira nota do aluno ? ");
scanf("%d", &Peso_1);
printf("Qual a segunda nota do aluno ? ");
scanf("%d", &Nota_2);
printf("Qual o peso da segunda nota do aluno ? ");
scanf("%d", &Peso_2);
Media = calcula_media_ponderada(Nota_1,Nota_2,Peso_1,Peso_2);
printf("A media do aluno da matricula %d e de %f",Matricula, Media);
return 0;
}
```

Na minha variável media aqui na penúltima linha se eu der as seguintes entradas respectivamente 123 (matricula)  7  7  3  3. a minha saída correta seria 5,8 porem sai 5,0 não consigo identificar o erro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está fazendo uma divisão de inteiros.
Por padrão, o C assume que a divisão entre dois inteiros, retornará um inteiro independente dos números após a virgula.

Para resolver este erro, a maneira mais simples, da forma que está seu código, é fazer um cast para float na hora da divisão.

Ficaria assim

```
float calcula_media_ponderada(int N_1, int N_2, int Peso_1, int Peso_2)
{
    float Media;
    Media = ((N_1 * Peso_1) + (N_2 * Peso_2)) / (float) (Peso_1 + Peso_2);
    return Media; 
}
```

O cast muda o tipo de uma variável momentaneamente, permitindo assim que você continue operando com valores inteiros pelo resto do programa. Porém o mais indicado seria você trabalhar com notas em float, mas isso depende do problema em si. A menos que o problema especifique que as notas só são inteiras, tente usar float.

Bons estudos!

Comment: Certo,Obrigado!